# Can we force "Open in Explorer" upon all users machines

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, onedrive

We have been using OneDrive as a local application to sync and to offline work with SharePoint files.  But our IT admin is not happy about the amount of space those files is taking locally. We have around 500 users and around 150 SharePoint sites. and users are just syncing all the libraries because they prefer to work and edit the files locally rather than using the online office apps.

So, is there a way to use the traditional way of working with files locally using the "Open in explore" option? so when the user accesses their windows "This Pc" to have a drive that is connected to selected sites? so the files will not be stored locally and will need a connection to be able to view and edit the files? is this a valid option?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting the document to be opened in a local app by default instead of the browser? If so, we recommend that you go to Settings > Library Settings > Advanced Settings > Select Open in Browser under Browser Enable Default Open Behavior for Documents.
[image]

Reference:[How to default Office files to open in the native app from SharePoint and OneDrive](https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-default-office-files-to-open-in-the-native-app-from-sharepoint-and-onedrive/)